# Where is my nbody orbital code going wrong? (Something in the math?)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In fortran, my nbody code worked flawlessly. When I translated it over to python I messed up somewhere. The code still successfully reads in a .txt file of bodies and still prints out a .txt file that records their position and velocity over each timestep. However, all my bodies seem to slingshot into the great unknown. I know this because when comparing the plots (using mathematica) I notice that my fortran Jupiter generated plot (First image below) is perfectly elliptical and stays within the given distances expected of Jupiter and my python generated plot (second image below) goes all the way out to a magnitude of 10^15 which is absurd. I'm assuming it's a simple fix in the math somewhere but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import math as mt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nbodies = int(input("Input the number of bodies:  "))
dt = int(input("Input the number of timesteps:  "))
ntimesteps = int(input("Max timestep:  "))
G = 6.6743E-11

def getFile():
    path = os.getcwd()
    global fileName
    fileName = input("What file?  ")
    inputFile = open(path + "\\" + str(fileName),"r")
    return(inputFile)

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    for char in inputString:
        if(char == '-'):
            return True
        try:
            float(char)
            return True
        except:
            return False
        
def readFile(inputFile):
    newdata = []
    data = []
    while True:
        line = inputFile.readline()
        #if the end of the file is reached
        if not line:
            break;
        rawdata = line.split(" ")
        for i in rawdata:
            if hasNumbers(i) == True:
                i = i.rstrip()
                newdata.append(i)
        if newdata:
            data.append(newdata)
        newdata = []
    inputFile.close()
    return(data)    

def emptyFile(fileName, datatype):
    path = os.getcwd()
    outfile = open(path + "\\" + fileName[:-4] + "_" + datatype + ".txt", "w")
    return(outfile)
           
inputFile = getFile()
Orbital = emptyFile(fileName, "Orbital")
nData = readFile(inputFile)
m = []
x = []
y = []
z = []
vx = []
vy = [] 
vz = []
for i in nData:
    if hasNumbers(i) == True:
        m.append(float(i[0]))
        x.append(float(i[1]))
        y.append(float(i[2]))
        z.append(float(i[3]))
        vx.append(float(i[4]))
        vy.append(float(i[5]))
        vz.append(float(i[6]))
mass = np.array(m)
xpos = np.array(x)
ypos = np.array(y)
zpos = np.array(z)
xvel = np.array(vx)
yvel = np.array(vy)
zvel = np.array(vz)
        

Fx = np.zeros(nbodies)
Fy = np.zeros(nbodies)
Fz = np.zeros(nbodies)


def CalcForce(axnew, aynew, aznew):
    axnew = np.zeros(nbodies)
    aynew = np.zeros(nbodies)
    aznew = np.zeros(nbodies)
    for i in range(nbodies):
        for j in range(nbodies): 
            if i!=j:
                xdiff = x[j] - x[i]
                ydiff = y[j] - y[i]
                zdiff = z[j] - z[i]
                r2 = (xdiff**2)+(ydiff**2)+(zdiff**2)
                C = (G*m[j]*m[i])/((r2)**(1.5))
                Fx[i] = Fx[i]+C*(xdiff)
                Fx[j] = Fx[j]-C*(xdiff)
                Fy[i] = Fy[i]+C*(ydiff)
                Fy[j] = Fy[j]-C*(ydiff)
                Fz[i] = Fz[i]+C*(zdiff)
                Fz[j] = Fz[j]-C*(zdiff)
                axnew[i] = np.divide(Fx[i],m[i])
                axnew[j] = np.divide(Fx[j],m[j])
                aynew[i] = np.divide(Fy[i],m[i])
                aynew[j] = np.divide(Fy[j],m[j])
                aznew[i] = np.divide(Fz[i],m[i])
                aznew[j] = np.divide(Fz[j],m[j])
            else:
                continue
    return axnew, aynew, aznew

axnew, aynew, aznew = CalcForce(axnew, aynew, aznew)

for k in range(ntimesteps):
    xpos = xpos + xvel * dt + 0.5 * axnew * dt**2
    ypos = ypos + yvel * dt + 0.5 * aynew * dt**2
    zpos = zpos + zvel * dt + 0.5 * aznew * dt**2
    axold = axnew
    ayold = aynew
    azold = aznew
    xvel = xvel + 0.5 * (axold + axnew) * dt
    yvel = yvel + 0.5 * (ayold + aynew) * dt
    zvel = zvel + 0.5 * (azold + aznew) * dt
    
    
    np.savetxt(Orbital, np.transpose([np.arange(1, nbodies+1), np.full(nbodies, k*dt), xpos, ypos, zpos]),fmt="%2i %20i %15.5E %15.5E %15.5E")
```

Above I have my newest version of the python code. The "CalcForce.axnew" called accelerations worked when there was no If statement for i!=j. It doesn't anymore and I'm naïve as to why. Removing it and going back to trying to return the accelerations just returns 0s when called outside the definition.

Here's useful input to copy to a .txt file. It includes 11 bodies from the Sun to a comet (including Pluto which I use for a good time comparison). It's done in all 3 cartesian coordinates based on each body's orbital inclination with total linear momentum conserved.

```
m         x         y       z     vx      vy      vz
1.988e30 -4.490e5  0.000  0.000  0.000 -1.600e1  -0.4247
3.285e23  5.790e10 0.000  0.000  0.000  4.701e4   5.772e3
4.867e24  1.080e11 0.000  0.000  0.000  3.496e4   2.077e3
5.972e24  1.494e11 0.000  0.000  0.000  2.980e4   0.000
6.390e23  2.280e11 0.000  0.000  0.000  2.399e4   0.775e3
1.898e27  7.783e11 0.000  0.000  0.000  1.306e4   0.299e3
5.683e26  1.434e12 0.000  0.000  0.000  9.671e3   0.421e3
8.681e25  2.871e12 0.000  0.000  0.000  6.799e3   0.091e3
1.024e26  4.495e12 0.000  0.000  0.000  5.427e3   0.168e3
1.309e22  7.376e12 0.000  0.000  0.000  4.532e3   1.399e3
2.200e14  5.300e12 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.951e3   0.309e3
```

[image: Fortran Generated Plot for Jupiter]

[image: Python Generated Plot for Jupiter]

My fortran code for comparison is

```
Module nbody
  integer, parameter:: n = 100
  integer:: nbodies, nTimesteps, i, k
  double precision:: m(n), x(n), y(n), z(n), vx(n), vy(n), vz(n)
  double precision:: axold(n), ayold(n), azold(n), axnew(n), aynew(n), aznew(n)
  double precision:: Fx(n), Fy(n), Fz(n)
  double precision:: dt, G = 6.6743D-11, r2, C, S = 1.989D30
  character:: infile*40, outfile*40
  character(len=20), parameter :: fmt0 = "(1X,I15)",fmt1 = "(1X,E30.10)",fmt2 = "(1X,E30.10,/)"
end module

Program Gravitas
  use nbody

  print*,'input the number of bodies'
  read*, nbodies
  print*, 'input filename'
  read*, infile
  print*, 'output filename'
  read*, outfile
  open(unit=42, file=infile, status='unknown')
  open(unit=43, file=outfile, status='unknown')

  
  read(42,*)
  Do i=1, nbodies
    read(42,*) m(i), x(i), y(i), z(i), vx(i), vy(i), vz(i)
  end do
  print*, 'input timestep(dt)'
  read*, dt
  print*, 'Tmax'
  read*, nTimesteps
  
  Do i=1, nbodies
    WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")real(k)*dt 
    WRITE(43,fmt0,advance="no")i 
    WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")x(i) 
    WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")y(i) 
    WRITE(43,fmt2,advance="no")z(i)   
  end do
  
  call calcforces
  
  Do k = 1, nTimesteps
    x = x + vx * dt + 0.5 * axnew * dt**2
    y = y + vy * dt + 0.5 * aynew * dt**2
    z = z + vz * dt + 0.5 * aznew * dt**2
    axold = axnew
    ayold = aynew
    azold = aznew
    call calcforces
    vx = vx + 0.5 * (axold + axnew) * dt
    vy = vy + 0.5 * (ayold + aynew) * dt
    vz = vz + 0.5 * (azold + aznew) * dt
    Do i = 1, nbodies
      WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")real(k)*dt 
      WRITE(43,fmt0,advance="no")i 
      WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")x(i) 
      WRITE(43,fmt1,advance="no")y(i) 
      WRITE(43,fmt2,advance="no")z(i) 
    end do

Subroutine calcforces
  use nbody
  Fx=0.0
  Fy=0.0
  Fz=0.0
  do i=1, nbodies
    do j=(i+1), (nbodies)
      xdiff = x(j)-x(i)
      ydiff = y(j)-y(i)
      zdiff = z(j)-z(i)
      r2 = (xdiff**2)+(ydiff**2)+(zdiff)**2
      C = (G*m(j)*m(i))/((r2)**1.5)
      Fx(i)=Fx(i)+C*(xdiff)
      Fx(j)=Fx(j)-C*(xdiff)
      Fy(i)=Fy(i)+C*(ydiff)
      Fy(j)=Fy(j)-C*(ydiff)
      Fz(i)=Fz(i)+C*(zdiff)
      Fz(j)=Fz(j)-C*(zdiff)
    end do
  end do

  axnew = Fx/m
  aynew = Fy/m
  aznew = Fz/m
end subroutine
```

Comment: In your nested for loop, in `CalcForce`, you start your loop at `i+1`, so you're "missing" the interaction force of `i` objects every iteration. Is that intended?

Comment: Could you add a link or paste a block to your fortran code?

Comment: @Charles 

By starting at i I get a float division by zero issue with my force constant:

C = (G*m[j]*m[i])/((r2)**(1.5))

Comment: @kendfss 
Sure. I'll include it in my post.

Comment: CalcForce does not change accelXN, accelYN, and accelZN, as you seem to assume it does.  You shouldn't need to convert between lists and nparrays so much.  And, by the way, `axnew = np.zeros(nbodies)` is a quicker way to generate a zero array.

Comment: @JoMi you should start the loop at zero, and skip the iteration if `i==j`, as in that case, `r2==0` which is why you get the division by zero error.

Comment: @Charles ah!, I gotchya. I changed it above to hopefully what you mean.
Now I'm back to square one with the accelerations still being the empty lists they start as when I call them outside the CalcForce definition. How do I call the updated lists out of it? I've completely updated my code above to show what I have now.

Comment: Your lists are local variables, meaning they only exist in the scope of the CalcForce function. You need to return the lists from the function and assign them to a global variable when you call the function.

Comment: @Charles and here lies one of my biggest issues. I'm doing all of this in spyder so maybe it's the environment (I'd doubt it but still it might be relevant) I start my CalcForce definition by setting my acceleration arrays to be global and then to update within my for loops. 
I then attempt to return them from my for loops but then it tells me "name 'axnew' is parameter and global"
So then I remove the global set up and try returning them only to now be told axnew is not defined outside the definition. I don't get what's missing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ce1NQji1 see this code here

Comment: @Charles it's still telling me it's undefined... I am honestly baffled

Comment: Can you update the code in the original question so that I can see what's wrong please?

Comment: @Charles updated

Comment: "Please debug my code for me" questions are not usually well-received here -- back in Ye Olden Days we would have closed this as "Too Localized" (asking a question specific to Person A's code, not a generic problem that other people are liable to run into). Today, the relevant close reason is "Too Broad". I'm very surprised to see this upvoted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254255/14122 discusses why non-canonical / OP-local questions are generally not helpful to our goal of building a long-tail FAQ-style knowledge base.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Except I'm asking why I'm getting an undefined error for a variable that is obviously defined in my code. Buzz off.